# Unrecognized VM option 'CMSClassUnloadingEnabledn-J-Xmx2Gn'

Tags: scala, sbt

I have installed scala, sbt on Mac. When I try to run sbt it gives an error  Unrecognized VM option 'CMSClassUnloadingEnabledn-J-Xmx2Gn'. I think there is an issue with JVM but could not find any help for this error.

More error info:
Did you mean '(+/-)CMSClassUnloadingEnabled'?
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: Try to execute: `echo $SBT_OPTS` and paste it in this answer

Comment: echo $SBT_OPTS does not show anything

Comment: After I uninstalled sbt, manually removed sbtopts and sbtopts.default in the /usr/local/etc, then installed sbt again, it works ok. It looks like the issue was that during the initial installation I ran this command: echo '-J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled\n-J-Xmx2G\n' >> /usr/local/etc/sbtopts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the sbt configuration is confused with regards to line breaks and
mangles something like

```
-J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-J-Xmx2G
```

into one line

Comment: For more context, to fix it you should open the sbt config file, mine(Max OSX) is at /usr/local/etc/sbtopts. Find the line contains '-J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled\n-J-Xmx2G\n' and replace the two \n as real new line. Also, it should happen if you followed the instructions from: http://sourabhbajaj.com/mac-setup/Scala/README.html, which is the top result from googling 'installing scala in max osx'

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue after I ran the command I ran this command: echo '-J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled\n-J-Xmx2G\n' >> /usr/local/etc/sbtopts.
It seems the file /usr/local/etc/sbtopts contained both options in same line, separated by \n, i.e. the actual contents of the file were -J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled\n-J-Xmx2G\n

The solution was to remove \n by editing this file, and pressing enter key instead, so that the contents of file /usr/local/etc/sbtopts look the way David mentioned in his response.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows machines, check next settings :

1. System properties / Advanced / Environment Variables
2. System variables
   2.1. e.g. Maven settings for Java 8 may have this setting which does not work on Java 17, as "CMSClassUnloadingEnabled" is disabled :

[image: Windows system properties :]