# Unrecognized VM option 'CMSClassUnloadingEnabled' when running ./sbt.sh

Tags: scala, jvm, sbt

I am trying to learn Scala through the [Creative Scala](https://www.creativescala.org/creative-scala.pdf) guide. However, I get an error when I try to run on terminal the command below that is on page 12.

> Now change to the directory we just created and run SBT.
>
> ```
> cd creative-scala-template
> ./sbt.sh
> ```

The error I get is:

```
Unrecognized VM option 'CMSClassUnloadingEnabled'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

It seems that the problem is with sbt?

I tried to follow the top comment in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35434870/unrecognized-vm-option-cmsclassunloadingenabledn-j-xmx2gn), that says to go to the folder `/usr/local/etc/sbtopts` and do some changes, but my folder `/usr/local/` is empty.

Can anyone tells me what I am likely doing wrong, please?

By doing `java -version` I get:

```
openjdk version "18.0.2" 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2+9-61)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2+9-61, mixed mode, sharing)
```

And `sbt -version` gets me:

```
sbt version in this project: 1.7.1
sbt script version: 1.7.1
```

---

After the solution by Tim, I am now getting a different error when running `./sbt.sh`. Does anyone knows how to fix this?

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The Security Manager is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
    at java.base/java.lang.System.setSecurityManager(System.java:416)
    at sbt.TrapExit$.installManager(TrapExit.scala:53)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:128)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:89)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:56)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The Security Manager is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the option is defined in the `sbt.sh` file itself, included in the template project. This option was removed in Java 14 and later, and the guide you are using was developed with an earlier Java version.

You can edit this file and delete the text `-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` from it.

All of the other options currently in that file are still supported as of Java 18.

The resulting command will look like this:

```
java -Xmx3g -Xms1g -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m -XX:+UseNUMA -XX:+UseParallelGC -jar sbt-launch.jar "$@"
```

Comment: I submitted a pull request to remove that option, and it was accepted: https://github.com/creativescala/creative-scala-template/pull/6. If you get the latest version of the template, this should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tim!!! I am now getting a different error. I edited my question to include it in the end. Can you also help with this one, please?

Comment: I think that's related to this issue, which hasn't been fixed yet: https://github.com/creativescala/creative-scala-template/issues/3. If I can find some time, I'll try to submit a fix. In the meantime, your best bet may be to install an older version of Java. If you use Java 17, it will only print a warning.

Comment: Tim, thanks a lot again! I switched to Java 17 but I ran into a long list of errors that start with `java.io.IOError: java.lang.RuntimeException: /packages cannot be represented as URI`, that I believe is the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60308229/scala-packages-cannot-be-represented-as-uri). My solution was to install Java 1.8 (available [here](https://www.java.com/pt-BR/download/)) and then switch my Java version to it following [this guide](https://medium.com/@devkosal/switching-java-jdk-versions-on-macos-80bc868e686a). Now it all seems to work!! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: In general, I’d stay away from options someone deemed useful for an ancient Java version and apparently never revised for newer versions. `-XX:+TieredCompilation` is obsolete, as it is the default and honestly, I don’t know what default `ReservedCodeCacheSize` has, but if it differs from `256m`, I’d rather trust the default than the decision someone made a decade ago for the JVM implementation of that time. There’s a tendency to ship software with tons of options in the startup, with rather esoteric reasoning, *if* anyone remembers who added them and why. Give the defaults a try…